# How to process with uncertain format of numbers and characters by C++?

Tags: c++, assembly

I'm trying to process some input. It's should be numbers or the program will throw an exception. But the format of numbers are uncertain which means it may be a normal decimal number (base 10) like 123, or a hexadecimal number (base 16) like 0x123. I want to convert them into a 32-bit unsigned int.

1. How can I achieve the goal simple and fast?

   In fact, I'm writing an assembler and trying to decode the pseudoinstruction like `DD 0x1, 0x2`.
2. So another question is, how can I convert a characters with "\x01" in plain text into a real char type variable equal to '\x01' in C++?
3. And what if it's a string and how can I extract them out?

Comment: You might want to look at [strtol](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtol).

Comment: Also useful for your plans: [`std::hex`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/hex)

Comment: For testing the correct input I would consider to use regular expressions.

Comment: Actually, the easiest way to get the numeric parsing done is to _clear_ the `std::ios_base::basefield` in the stream's formatting flags: it will start parsing the field values automatically as hex (with starting with a `0x` prefix), as oct (starting with a `0` prefix), and as decimal otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I'm only interested in the first part of the question: how to read numeric values based on their prefix efficient and fast. The simple answer it to take advantage of the standard C++ library facilities for numeric parsing (BTW, I'm perfectly aware of the `%i` format specifier but I have no inclination to advertise C's facilities for numeric parsing): when the `std::ios_base::basefield` is cleared, the values are interpreted according to a prefix:

- `0x` => hexadecimal
- `0` => octal
- otherwise => decimal

Here is a short program demonstrating this feature::

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream in("0x123 0123 123");
    in.setf(std::ios_base::fmtflags(), std::ios_base::basefield);
    for (int i; in >> i; ) {
        std::cout << "read " << i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also another option than pointed out by Dietmar. It works in the same way: sets the numeric base of the stream to 0, which corresponds to decimal output and prefix-dependent input:

0x - hexadecimal

0 - octal

otherwise - decimal

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    std::istringstream s("10 0x10 010");
    s >> std::setbase(0);
    for (int i; s >> i; ) {
        std::cout << "read " << i << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

result:

read 10

read 16

read 8